# Can't get References to work in TeXnicCentre

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, texniccenter

First question, and an account made specifically for it. I'm having trouble getting citations to work from my bib file. I've spent the last several hours trying to get it to work, and as far as I can tell - I'm doing everything correctly! However, it is still not working. Even with the simplest files, I can't get teXnicCentre to read the citations inside my bib file, and cite them as expected. For a minimum working example, I have a tex file:

```
\documentclass[%
oneside
,bibliography=totoc
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{reflist.bib}

\begin{document}
Creating a computerized model of the system then becomes part of the process to achieve deeper understanding of the phenomena, alongside observations and analytic theory \citep{Narita2004}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where the context in reflist.bib is a single citation:

```
@article{Narita2004,
author = {Narita, Y. and Glassmeier, K.-H. and Sch{\"{a}}fer, S. and Motschmann, U. and Fr{\"{a}}nz, M. and Dandouras, I. and Forna{\c{c}}on, K.-H. and Georgescu, E. and Korth, a. and R{\`{e}}me, H. and Richter, I.},
doi = {10.5194/angeo-22-2315-2004},
issn = {1432-0576},
journal = {Annales Geophysicae},
keywords = {electromagnetics,inter-,physics,planetary bow shocks,planetary physics,space plasma,tions which are unstable,to different types of,wave propagation,waves and instabilities,waves at vari-},
pages = {2315--2323},
title = {{Alfv{\'{e}}n waves in the foreshock propagating upstream in the plasma rest frame: statistics from Cluster observations}},
volume = {22},
year = {2004}
}
```

The .bib citation was generated by Mendeley (the database software I'm using), and although it looks messy it should still work as expected (to my knowledge). I'm trying to use the natbib commands in biblatex because I like the use of their /citep{} and /citet{} functions.

Any help? This has taken up far too much of my time already!

PS: When I run the files in TXC, all the aux, bbl, etc. files are generated. The .bbl file is blank (so no citations were sourced). In the .blg file, it states:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: example.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file example.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file example.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file example.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Yet, in the .aux file:

```
\relax 
\providecommand*\new@tpo@label[2]{}
\abx@aux@sortscheme{nty}
\abx@aux@refcontext{nty/global/}
\abx@aux@cite{Narita2004}
\abx@aux@segm{0}{0}{Narita2004}
\@writefile{toc}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lof}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lot}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
```

I can see my citation key sitting in there, meaning that it actually *has* recognized that I've cited something... and for some reason it hasn't been picked up with it goes through the .bib file.

All files are in the same directory.

Comment: Recent versions of biblatex (actually for some time now) default to the use of biber rather than bibtex. You might have to add the option [backend=bibtex] for biblatex or have the front end run biber rather than bibtex.

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't aware of this. Changing the backend made everything fall into place. Thanks!

Comment: This is most certainly a duplicate of [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). Do you agree?